# Authentication error using phpmyadmin and docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose

I'm trying to user docker-compose for mysql and phpmyadmin, but I'm getting an authentication error when trying to log in to phpmyadmin.

I've tried several configurations on the yaml file, but without any success.

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: admin

    volumes:
      my-db: {}
```

When I try logging in to phpmyadmin i get the following  errors:

> mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
>   mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

I tried to change the yml to:

```
version: '3'

  services:

    db:
      image: mysql:57
      restart: always
      environment:
```

After this, the container no longer starts, and it gives the following message:

> docker_db_1 exited with code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
          image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
          links:
            - db
          ports:
            - 8080:80
          restart: always
          environment:
              PMA_USER: root
              PMA_PASSWORD: admin

volumes:
  my-db: {}
```

Remember to delete the volume before running (in case you run into issues).

Comment: It worked. I removed the volume and used your example and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied this code in docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
          image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
          links:
            - db
          ports:
            - 8080:80
          restart: always
          environment:
              PMA_USER: root
              PMA_PASSWORD: admin

volumes:
  my-db: {}
```

and ran the command `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml  mysqllab`

This is the result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep10d.png)